# Can't execute Query in EF6.3

Tags: .net, exception, entity-framework-6

I have the following query:

```
var result = await _dbContext.ApplicationItems.ToListAsync();
```

At runtime I get an exception on that query line:

[image]

I don't know why this exception is happening.

The class ApplicationItem looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationItem : EntityBase
{
    public List<ApplicationItemRole> ApplicationItemRoles { get; set; } = new List<ApplicationItemRole();
    public string AssemblyName { get; set; }
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ViewModelType { get; set; }
}
```

and EntityBase has only one public property Id;

Comment: Parameterized constructors (where the property assignment occurs through the constructor) is only supported in EF Core, not in EF6. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors

Comment: Tried this, I removed constructors and used object initialization. But still the exception happens. :-(

Comment: You will also need to make the default constructor `public` instead of `protected`

Comment: I did' I updated the question sample

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong here. Do you have any third-party libraries installed, e.g. for global query filters?

Comment: Yes, I use Z.EntityFramework.Extensions

Comment: Then you should post this issue in their support site.

Comment: Not the problem, with Z.EntityFramework.Extensions I found the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in my solution of 24 projects there was an older version of EF installed package. So When I updated this package, all problems have gone away. All working now.